Why I can't open the further info URL of variant IDs in CMIP6 models?
For example, The URL is: http://furtherinfo.es-doc.org/CMIP6.IPSL.IPSL-CM6A-LR.abrupt-4xCO2.none.r1i1p1f1
I can't open it, I clicked on this URL and it showed 502. Why?

A 502 (bad gateway) error is a catch-all for lots of problems, most of which you, the user, cannot fix. Where did you get that link? Maybe it was a bad link. I too received a 502 error when I clicked on that link, so the problem most likely is not on your end.
It turns out that https://furtherinfo.es-doc.org all by itself results in a 502 (bad gateway) error. The problem is with that website. Once again, where did you get that link?

Thanks your answer, I got this link form https://es-doc.org/cmip6-ensembles-further-info-url/    this website is available.
In fact, CMIP6 has a general definition for variant labels, but if I want to know the specific differences between variants of a model, I need further information. But I can't open this link.

@ChenxiLi This is not the first time, and certainly not the last time that a website let itself go out of date with bad internal links. In this case, it looks like es-doc.org has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/ES-DOC-INSTITUTIONAL . Perhaps the further info you want is there rather than on the organization's own website. The GitHub site appears to be quite up to date while their self-maintained site appears to be out of date.

Thanks a lot!!! I'll look for them.
